# WCF A call to SSPI failed, 'the target principal name is incorrect'

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-security

I'm getting this dreaded message and have spent a fair bit of time reading about it but have still been unable to solve it

I have a console app running on my client trying to invoke a WCF service on a different machine.  The service is running under a domain account.  I believe under this scenario it tries to authenticate using Kerberos

I have also read that if you supply a dummy serviceprincipalname on the client

```
<servicePrincipalName value="MySystem/Service1"/>
```

then it will fall back to using ntml.

I have tried this without luck.  If the client is on the same machine as the service then it works fine.  Not sure what else I can try.  Here is the config on my client

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
          <binding name="NetTcpBinding_HelpersService" />
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="net.tcp://myserver/SPInterface/HelpersService.svc/TCP" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_HelpersService"
    contract="HelpersService" name="NetTcpBinding_HelpersService">
           <identity>
             <servicePrincipalName value="MySystem/Service1"/>
           </identity>
       </endpoint>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

What I also don't understand is that if I use the WCFTestClient in Visual Studio which generates the same config file from my local machine it works fine

My server config files has this in it:-

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">
       <serviceActivations>
        <add relativeAddress="HelpersService.svc" service="SPInterface.Models.HelpersService" factory="SPInterface.WebService.HelpersServiceHostFactory"/>
        </serviceActivations>
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
    <services>
        <service name="SPInterface.Models.HelpersService" behaviorConfiguration="Debug">
            <endpoint address="TCP" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingNamespace="http://Server/SPInterface/Services" contract="SPInterface.Contracts.IHelpersService"/>
            <endpoint address="Rest" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingNamespace="http://Server/SPInterface/Services" contract="SPInterface.Contracts.IHelpersService" behaviorConfiguration="Rest"/>
       </service>
    </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

The inner exception is "the target principal name is incorrect"

Comment: And what does the inner exception say?

Comment: Good point! It says "the target principal name is incorrect".  Just amended the question